# How do I tell NuGet that I do NOT want a particular dependancy from a package?

Tags: nuget

There's a particular package that I like for my project that is on NuGet.  However, the package author has decided to include several dependant packages that I don't care for and are not required by the main package.  I have tried convincing the package author that these should be separate packages and not dependancies - to no avail.

Is there a way to tell NuGet that I want a package but to exclude a dependancy?

Perhaps something in the packages.config like this or similar?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="SomePackage" version="1.0.0">
    <ignoredependancy id="SomePackage.UselessStuff" />
  </package>
</packages>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

Install-Package  -IgnoreDependencies

or

Uninstall-Package  -Force

Comment: Can you give the details on this answer? Where is IgnoreDependencies located from a GUI, or is it only from the command line. Does it change a config file? Same questions for Force.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a feature request you should open an issue on the [Nuget Codeplex site](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)